# How to insert a detail activity in the android app?

Tags: java, android

I'm beginner in Android app development and following the Udacity course for developing weather app. The app looks like the following,

[image]
Now, I'm trying to insert a functionality so that if the user taps on the particular day weather, it will open detail info for that day. So, I insert new Activity source file namely `DetailActivity.java` with the parent as `MainActivity.java` and inserted the following code,

```
    package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class DetailActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.detail, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

            Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
            if (intent != null && intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {

                String forecastStr = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                ((TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.detail_text))
                        .setText(forecastStr);
            }

            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

The `fragment_detail.xml` file mentioned inside the `onCreateView` method is as following,

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivity.DetailFragment">

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/detail_text"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The app opens fine, but, crushes after tapping to enter for detail info. I get the following error in the `AndroidStudio`,

```
Process: com.example.android.sunshine.app, PID: 9380
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.sunshine.app/com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08003f (com.example.android.sunshine.app:id/container) for fragment ForecastFragment{d216488 #0 id=0x7f08003f}
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
```

I think the issue is `No view found for id 0x7f08003f (com.example.android.sunshine.app:id/container) for fragment ForecastFragment{d216488 #0 id=0x7f08003f}`

The `ForecastFragement.java` is the another source file that provides the weather data.  Initially, it's showing the mock data and there are code to fetch real time info and that part is just fine. I have a file inside the `layout` folder namely `activity_main.xml` that has the `id` with name `container`. the source code for the `activity_main.xml` file is as follwoing,

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

How to run the `DetailActivity` in the app properly ? If you need more info for trouble shooting, just ask me.

Note:

As answer of the question asked, I have `activity_detail.xml` inside the `layout` folder and looks as following,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Okay, I was not intended to put a lot of code in this question, however, as asked, I provide the `ForecastFragement.java` below,

```
    package com.example.android.sunshine.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * Created by Chaklader on 3/9/16.
 */
public class ForecastFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mForecastAdapter;

    public ForecastFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events.
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.forecastfragment, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {

            FetchWeatherTask fetchWeatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
            fetchWeatherTask.execute("14129");
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



    @Override
    public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Create some dummy data for the ListView.  Here's a sample weekly forecast
        String[] data = {

                "Mon 6/23 - Sunny - 31/17",
                "Tue 6/24 - Foggy - 21/8",
                "Wed 6/25 - Cloudy - 22/17",
                "Thurs 6/26 - Rainy - 18/11",
                "Fri 6/27 - Foggy - 21/10",
                "Sat 6/28 - TRAPPED IN WEATHERSTATION - 23/18",
                "Sun 6/29 - Sunny - 20/7"
        };

        List<String> weekForecast = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(data));

        // Now that we have some dummy forecast data, create an ArrayAdapter.
        // The ArrayAdapter will take data from a source (like our dummy forecast) and
        // use it to populate the ListView it's attached to.
        mForecastAdapter =

                new ArrayAdapter<String>(

                        getActivity(), // The current context (this activity)
                        R.layout.list_item_forecast, // The name of the layout ID.
                        R.id.list_item_forecast_textview, // The ID of the textview to populate.
                        weekForecast);

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_forecast);
        listView.setAdapter(mForecastAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                String forecast = mForecastAdapter.getItem(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class)
                        .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, forecast);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }


    public class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String[]> {

        private final String LOG_TAG = FetchWeatherTask.class.getSimpleName();

        /* The date/time conversion code is going to be moved outside the asynctask later,
         * so for convenience we're breaking it out into its own method now.
         */
        private String getReadableDateString(long time) {

            // Because the API returns a unix timestamp (measured in seconds),
            // it must be converted to milliseconds in order to be converted to valid date.
            SimpleDateFormat shortenedDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd");
            return shortenedDateFormat.format(time);
        }

        /**
         * Prepare the weather high/lows for presentation.
         */
        private String formatHighLows(double high, double low) {

            // For presentation, assume the user doesn't care about tenths of a degree.
            long roundedHigh = Math.round(high);
            long roundedLow = Math.round(low);

            String highLowStr = roundedHigh + "/" + roundedLow;
            return highLowStr;
        }


        /**
         * Take the String representing the complete forecast in JSON Format and
         * pull out the data we need to construct the Strings needed for the wireframes.
         * <p/>
         * Fortunately parsing is easy:  constructor takes the JSON string and converts it
         * into an Object hierarchy for us.
         */
        private String[] getWeatherDataFromJson(String forecastJsonStr, int numDays)
                throws JSONException {

            // These are the names of the JSON objects that need to be extracted.
            final String OWM_LIST = "list";
            final String OWM_WEATHER = "weather";
            final String OWM_TEMPERATURE = "temp";
            final String OWM_MAX = "max";
            final String OWM_MIN = "min";
            final String OWM_DESCRIPTION = "main";

            JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(forecastJsonStr);
            JSONArray weatherArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_LIST);

            // OWM returns daily forecasts based upon the local time of the city that is being
            // asked for, which means that we need to know the GMT offset to translate this data
            // properly.

            // Since this data is also sent in-order and the first day is always the
            // current day, we're going to take advantage of that to get a nice
            // normalized UTC date for all of our weather.

            Time dayTime = new Time();
            dayTime.setToNow();

            // we start at the day returned by local time. Otherwise this is a mess.
            int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);

            // now we work exclusively in UTC
            dayTime = new Time();
            String[] resultStrs = new String[numDays];

            for (int i = 0; i < weatherArray.length(); i++) {

                // For now, using the format "Day, description, hi/low"
                String day;
                String description;
                String highAndLow;

                // Get the JSON object representing the day
                JSONObject dayForecast = weatherArray.getJSONObject(i);

                // The date/time is returned as a long.  We need to convert that
                // into something human-readable, since most people won't read "1400356800" as
                // "this saturday".
                long dateTime;
                // Cheating to convert this to UTC time, which is what we want anyhow
                dateTime = dayTime.setJulianDay(julianStartDay + i);
                day = getReadableDateString(dateTime);

                // description is in a child array called "weather", which is 1 element long.
                JSONObject weatherObject = dayForecast.getJSONArray(OWM_WEATHER).getJSONObject(0);
                description = weatherObject.getString(OWM_DESCRIPTION);

                // Temperatures are in a child object called "temp".  Try not to name variables
                // "temp" when working with temperature.  It confuses everybody.
                JSONObject temperatureObject = dayForecast.getJSONObject(OWM_TEMPERATURE);
                double high = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MAX);
                double low = temperatureObject.getDouble(OWM_MIN);

                highAndLow = formatHighLows(high, low);
                resultStrs[i] = day + " - " + description + " - " + highAndLow;
            }

            for (String s : resultStrs) {

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast entry: " + s);
            }

            return resultStrs;
        }


        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(String... params) {

            // If there's no zip code, there's nothing to look up.  Verify size of params.
            if (params.length == 0)
                return null;


            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;

            String format = "json";
            String units = "metric";
            int numDays = 7;

            try {

                // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
                // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
                // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
                final String FORECAST_BASE_URL =
                        "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";

                final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
                final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
                final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
                final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";
                final String APPID_PARAM = "APPID";
                String appID = "6a2d7bcc0ccd7c6269addc6f1af23c8b";

                Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                        .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                        .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                        .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                        .appendQueryParameter(APPID_PARAM, appID)
                        .build();


                URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());
                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Built URI " + builtUri.toString());

                // Create the request to OpenWeatherMap, and open the connection
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }

                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();

                Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Forecast string: " + forecastJsonStr);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attemping
                // to parse it.
                return null;
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }

            try {
                return getWeatherDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr, numDays);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // This will only happen if there was an error getting or parsing the forecast.
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {

            if (result != null) {

                mForecastAdapter.clear();
                for (String dayForecastStr : result) {
                    mForecastAdapter.add(dayForecastStr);
                }
                // New data is back from the server.  Hooray!
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `activity_detail.xml` in your layout folder?

Comment: Can you put your ForecastFragment class?

Comment: Yes, I gave the source code for the `activity_detail.xml` in the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be your `activity_detail.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

You're missing `android:id` for your view. So the class can't find the id of `container` view

Comment: YES, this works now. I really appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I might be incorrect, since I'm uncertain if you have xml file for the ForecastFragment. As you can see, the PlaceholderFragment is associated with **fragment_detail.xml**.

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);
```

Quick fix is instead of instantiating ForecastFragment() here:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new ForecastFragment())
                .commit();
```

Instantiate the PlaceholderFragment like so:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment ())
                .commit();
```

True fix is probably that you need to override onCreateView in your ForecastFragment and associate it to **details.xml** or whatever xml file you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I visited the source code of Udacity. They named the `PlaceholderFragement` as `DetailedFragement` and initiated they way you have mentioned. Surprisingly, I'm still getting the same error and provided inside the next comment. I changed the name `PlaceholderFragement` as `DetailedFragement`.

Comment: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.sunshine.app/com.example.android.sunshine.app.DetailActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f08003f (com.example.android.sunshine.app:id/container) for fragment DetailFragment{7fbb82f #0 id=0x7f08003f}
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)`